# linking and using a C++ library with an Objective-C application

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, linker, dylib

I'm writing a graphical application using Objective-C for the front end and C++ for the graphics processing and network communication. I read around on Apple's site looking for a way to link either a **.dylib** or **.so** with my C++ code in it to my Xcode project, but nothing seemed to work. I was able to get the project to reference it and link against it, but when I tried to call functions from that .dylib, it was saying that it didn't know what I was trying to do.  Does anyone know what is going on here?

I know that Objective-C has all the libraries I would need to do graphics and networking, but I just feel like doing it like this. I haven't done much C++ in a while and I want to learn more Objective-C, so what better way than to use them together?

Thanks,
Robbie

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're going to hit one obstacle in the form of what's called "name mangling". C++ stores function names in a way not compatible with Obj-C.

Objective-C doesn't implement classes in the same way as C++, so it's not going to like it.

One way around this is to implement a set of simple C functions which call the C++ functions. It'll be a good challenge to keep the number of C functions as low as possible! You'll end up with a nice compact interface! :)

To declare these functions in a C++ file, you'll need to mark them as C with:

```
extern "C" int function_name(char *blob,int number, double foo) {...}
```

This disables the standard name-mangling.

Build a header file with the prototypes for all these functions that you can share with your objective C code.

You won't be able to pass classes around in the same way (because your ObjC code can't use them), but you'll be able to pass pointers (although you might have to lie about the types a little).

Comment: Another option is to make your Objective-C files Objective-C++ files by changing their extension to .mm and then you can mix your C++ and Objective-C code.

Comment: This worked for me. I created a class in an `.mm` file and was able to link against C++ libraries perfectly, and call the wrapper methods from my .`m` files. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Most of the projects I work on have an ObjC frontend and C++ backend. If you're dealing exclusively with functions, then Dave Gamble's name mangle fix is correct, but if you're dealing with more complex situations, where you need to deal with both ObjC and C++ objects, your best bet is to wrap the C++ objects in ObjC objects. Using opaque references (which is a very fancy way of saying `void*`), you can actually hand around C++ objects in ObjC and vice versa. I have some [sample code](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-objc-20) that may be helpful.

That said, for graphics you're probably going to take a serious performance hit doing custom C++ rather than using Core Image and the related frameworks. Core Image and the other graphics frameworks are highly optimized for the Mac, and you're very unlikely to do better with hand-rolled C++ (or even very well-written C++ that isn't specifically for the Mac). As you move to 10.6 and grand central dispatch, the performance difference is going to be even more notable because you'll lose all the parallelization advances that you would get for free otherwise. This has nothing to do with ObjC; Core Image is C. You can call it from C++ all you like. I just recommend against custom graphics processing on Mac in any language unless you need portability or you have the expertise necessary to beat Core Image.

Comment: Hi, In presented example as I can see you are wrapping a C++ object into Objective-C++ (.mm file extension) and not into Objective-C (.m file extension). As I understand you cannot have an Objective-C object **A** which uses wrapper Objective-C++ object **B**. You have to change extensions of every `.m` file to `.mm`. Thus you have to make your project Objective-C++ !

Comment: That's not true. As long as `B.h` is pure ObjC (declares no C++), you can absolutely call `B` from `A`. You absolutely don't have to change every `.m` to `.mm` (and should not).